# Spring dependency injection with multiple implementation for an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

So, this interface has 2 implementations. I want to validate the input with all the implementations of the interface and return the implementation object whatever satisfies the condition.

**Interface:**

```java
interface SomeInterface {
     boolean someCheck(int n);
}
```

**Implementation 1:**

```java
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
   public boolean someCheck(int n) {
      // returns true if n is less than 10
   }
}
```

**Implementation 2:**

```
public class AnotherClass implements SomeInterface {
   public boolean someCheck(int n) {
      // returns true if n is greater than 10
   }
}
```

Can I use the dependency injection concept here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both implementations are spring beans, you can inject both implementations in the list:

```
public class Validator {

   @Autowired
   private List<SomeInterface> allImplementations;
    
   public boolean validate(int n) {
      for(SomeInterface impl : allImplementations) {
          if(!impl.someCheck(n)) {
              return false;
          }
       }
       return true; // all validations passed
   }

   
}
```